# Multiple instances of bash script upon logout and login

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I made simple script which works in infinite loop. It looks like that:

```
while :
do
   #operations
   sleep 5
done
```

and I added it to autorun programs [like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login).

Everything works fine but after logout I have 2 instances of this script process (3 after next logout and so on). Only one of them show notifications but they both run own `sleep` processes.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you want the script to continue running after you logout, or should it be terminated at that time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log out doesn't kill all processes. You need to kill that process yourself. One way is to add conditional `kill` inside your script.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for proc in $(pgrep $(basename "$0"));do
[[ $proc -ne $$ ]] && kill $proc
done
while :
do
   #operations
  sleep 5
done
```

If you run this script twice, the second one will kill the previous one/s and make sure only one instance of this script is running at a time.

If there are more than one users who use that process then you might want it to be user specific. For that, change the line:

```
[[ $proc -ne $$ ]] && kill $proc
```

to:

```
[[ $(echo $(pgrep -u $USER) | grep -o $proc) -ne $$ ]] && kill $proc
```

Note: Sometimes, your process can get into a defunct state when normal `kill` command won't be enough to kill them. Use `kill -9` in those cases.

Comment: What if two users use the script in autorun programs in parallel?